# Using Sequelize FN function to query a date column

Tags: sequelize.js

I try to use the `fn()` function of SequelizeJS to query a `date` column by searching the day (1...31).

**My code :**

```
// day = 1
// date of today = 2023-08-01
Sequelize.where(models.Sequelize.fn('DAY', models.Sequelize.col('invoice.date')), day)
```

With my code it works but I get the lines of the next days.

To fix my code I need to pull out one number on the `day` variable but It's only work between 2 and the last day of the month.

Do you have any idea to fix the query using `fn()` function of SequelizeJS ?

Comment: Please indicate your DBMS type and version